# Kubernetes Minikube driver and running it inside a VM manager?

Tags: docker, kubernetes, minikube, kvm

I have 2 questions as I am currently trying to learn minikube and now wants to install it;

1- Which driver is preferable for Minikube (KVM or docker) ? Does one have some sort of advantage over other ?

2- Is it possible to install and run the minkube inside a VM managed by KVM ?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

1 - There is no "better" or "worse". Using Docker is the default and with that the most supported version.
2 - Yes, it is possible to run Minikube inside a VM.

Answer (score 0):

Found more answers to my question after some digging in the documentation.

https://minikube.sigs.k8s.io/docs/drivers/

As there are options available but when using minikub inside a VM then preferred driver will be either none or ssh. I ran into some networking issues when initially used docker but resolved it after digging more into the documentation. Otherwise docker is fine unless someone who is expert in resolving networking issues between the host and guest(vm)